# how to pass a value of a control from one page to another using ajax in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to pass a value of a  control(For example a textbox) from one page to another using ajax in asp.net with c#.

any suggestions

Comment: use PreviousPage property...

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: @GopeshSharma this wont always work if you are using ajax

Comment: @IamStalker - Oh, I didn't knew that...thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="Submit" id="btn">

<script>
$(document).ready(function()({
           $("#btn").click(function() {
                  Var textData = $("#txt").val();
                  $.ajax({
                      url:"Home/Index/" //In case of MVC.
                      type:'get'
                      data:{data:textData}
                      success: function() { 
                           Your code..........
                     }
               });
});
```